# Get content-scheme Uri of an image via MediaScannerConnectionClient

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

I have some pictures stored in the external SD card and I want to show their thumbnails in a `GridView`. I know that the media scanner has created the thumbnails because I can browse my pictures folder with the standard Gallery application but I don't know where those thumbnails are located so I don't know how to add them to my `GridView`.

I'm trying to get the thumbnails with:

```
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), Long.parseLong(_imageUri.getLastPathSegment()), type, null)
```

The `_imageUri` must be a content-schema Uri so my problem is to find a way of converting the file-schema Uris of my images into content-schema Uris. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it. I've seen lots of SO threads recommending to use `Uri.parse()` but it just doesn't work so I'm looking for a different solution.

My current approach is to use the media scanner for scanning individual files and try to retrieve the content `Uri` from the `onScanCompleted` callback. The code is:

```
public class SimpleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {
    private MediaScannerConnection mMSC;
    private File mFile;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;

    public SimpleMediaScanner(Context c, File f, MyAdapter a) {
        mAdapter = a;
        mFile = f;
        mMSC = new MediaScannerConnection(c, this);
        mMSC.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mMSC.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        // Store the content scheme Uri of the scanned file
        // in a public field of the adapter
        mAdapter.mThumbUri = uri;
        mMSC.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I instantiate this class from my extended `SimplecursorAdapter`:

```
SimpleMediaScanner sms = new SimpleMediaScanner(mContext, new File(filepath), this);
```

Unfortunately the returned `mAdapter.mThumbUri` value is always `null`. Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [MediaStorage.Images.Thumbnails](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html) class? It provides two static `getThumbnail(...)` methods that should fulfill your needs.